# can i fill the UK visa application for my family who reside in another country

Tags: visas, applications

I live in US and my wife and daughter live in Nigeria.
We will be visiting the UK this christmas.

Is it okay to fill the application forms on their behalf from the US as i have all their information to avoid mistakes from their end.

I go through forms like these 3 times to ensure everything is correct and accurate, My wife does not have that kind of dedication.

I will be filling mine here though, even though i will not be able to link them together as we are far apart. We plan to both make the trip to the UK, spend quality family time together and back to our respective country of residence.

Will this be an issue because my IP address will clearly show i filled the forms.
Thanks.

Comment: Omo Naija, you are thinking too much. IP address conflict? Hahahaha, I beg go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to stop you completing the forms on their behalf, they will both have to sign their respective applications and are ultimately responsible for what they contain. You should also ensure they understand what their individual application states, in case they are asked about the contents when they arrive in the UK